# Function to insert integers in an array in a sorted way

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, integer

So assuming that i start with an array [0,0,0,0]. And in this array i will be adding exactly 4 values. Lets say 2,1,3,4. So my main function will look like:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[4];
        insertSortedInArr(2,arr);
        insertSortedInArr(1,arr);
        insertSortedInArr(3,arr);
        insertSortedInArr(4,arr);
    }
```

I tried an implementation of a method `insertSortedInArr()` which i also found online, but it is not quite working. I tried to find what goes wrong with it but i couldn't manage to find the bug. This is the method:

```
 public static void insertSortedInArr(int val,int[] arr){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
            if (arr[i] == 0){
                arr[i] = val;
                return;
            }
            if (val < arr[i])
                // value must be inserted in arr[i]
                break;
        }
        // move everything right
        for(int k=i; k<arr.length-1; k++){
                arr[k+1]=arr[k];
        }
        arr[i]=val;
    }
```

My output of this method gives me: `[1, 2, 2, 4]`.
If you could find what's going wrong or have a better implementation of this method it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the “move everything right” part.

You are iterating from left to right, but this will overwrite the next element.

Instead, iterate from right to left:

```
for (int k=arr.length-1; k > i; k--){
    arr[k]=arr[k - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know already the values, I think we don't even need a loop here. We can just do the following :

```
public static void insertSorted(int val, int arr[]) {
    if(arr[val - 1] == 0) { 
        arr[val-1] = val;
    }
}
```

or better, just insert the values to array in random order, and use

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

Hope that it helps.

Comment: That's unlikely to help because in the first case array will be unsorted because it will may look like [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 4]; in the second case zero values will be moved forward: [0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 2, 4]

Comment: Please find the passes below,

Pass 0: [0,0,0,0]
Pass 1: [0,2,0,0]
pass 2 : [1,2,0,0]
pass 3 : [1,2,3,0]
pass 4 : [1,2,3,4]

Comment: Yes, and for each intermediate step the array is unsorted as you should be able to see.

Comment: Right. I thought the end result is the sorted array. Nice that you mentioned this point.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a minor improvement related to detection of the first free element where available values should be moved:

```java
public static void insertSortedInArr(int val, int[] arr) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 0) {
            break;
        } else if (val < arr[i]) {
            int j;
            for (j = i + 1; arr[j] != 0 && j < arr.length; j++); // find first 0
            for (int k = j; k > i; k--) { // shift elements right to the first free cell
                arr[k] = arr[k - 1];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    arr[i] = val;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Test:

```java
int[] arr = new int[4];
insertSortedInArr(4,arr);
insertSortedInArr(2,arr);
insertSortedInArr(1,arr);
insertSortedInArr(3,arr);
```

Output:

```
[4, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 4, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 4, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```